# How to find Executable References programmatically

Tags: windows, operating-system

I have a server with many executables files (.exe, .dll) but this files used to link to another executables too... and so on.
To prevent deployment errors, I need a way to search for every dependency and it's dependencies and check for any platform incompatibility (32 or 64 bits).

I have no problem to detect the binaries's platform but I don't know how to get a list of dependencies.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I'm using C#, but I can use Delphi, C or C++

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://www.dependencywalker.com/ - this is the best tool for seeing the module dependency hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

This question seems to get asked regularly here. I don't recommend reverse engineering your dependencies as you propose. The problem is the on different platforms the dependencies may differ. If you can you should work it out from the source. This is not as hard as it may seem at first glance.

Answer (score 0):

For managed code you can use Reflection to go through all the managed dependencies, and the Dependency Walker that tenfour pointed out should help with the native. Problems will arise when you start factoring in other types of dependencies that are not as easily checked: registry keys, COM, configuration files/settings.

Your best bet would be to develop a set of acceptance tests for deploying to your server or setting up some of staging before pushing to a live server. This will help catch deployment errors as well as a number of other functional defects that might have slipped through initial testing.